# Calculate a formula from one cell in a sheet and paste the result in another different cell from another different sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I know how to code the formula but not how to make them move from a sheet to another

Basically the idea is that user types data in one sheet, and then they get the result of the formula in another sheet from the same excel

Comment: Its difficult without knowing the formula you are wanting, but why not place the formula where you want the result to be and reference the cell where the value is being entered? A quick example if the user is entering the data in Sheet1 cell A1 and you want the result to be that data multiplied by 5 in Sheet2 A1, then in Sheet2 A1 you would enter the following: `=Sheet1!A1*5`

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the reply!How do I do that? The formulas I use are simple divisions, like imagine for ex cell  "C6"/"C9". All I need to do is once the formula is calculated, paste the result in an specific cell from another sheet

Comment: Ex: Formula "C6"/"C9" is in sheet one and should be pasted in sheet 2 "E5" cell. Also the sheets have diff names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the formula `=C6/C9` in placed in cell `C10`.

If you want to use VBA then you can place the following code under the Sheet that has the formulas and specify which sheet you want the result to go into as below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet2")
'declare and set the worksheet the data is to be copied into, amend the sheet name as required
If Target.Address = "$C$6" Or Target.Address = "$C$9" Then 'if anything changes in C6 or C9 in this sheet
    ws.Range("E5").Value = Target.Parent.Range("C10") 'copy the value from cell C10 in this sheet to Sheet2 in cell E5
End If
End Sub
```

You could also do this without VBA, in Sheet2 in cell E5 you could also enter the following and would achieve the same result:
`=Sheet1!C10`

Or you could even enter in Sheet2 E5 the actual formula you want to calculate as:

`=Sheet1!C6/Sheet1!C9`

Comment: Just a note `ActiveSheet` is not necessarily the same worksheet as where `Target` is in. Use `Target.Parent` instead of `ActiveSheet`. There is a rare situation where `ActiveSheet` will fail. Eg. User starts editing C6 (but doesn't exit edit mode) and immediately clicks on another Sheet (switches sheet). In this case `ActiveSheet` is not `Target.Parent` and it will fail.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ thanks for the comment, updated my answer now.. :)